# Let $f(x)=x^2\operatorname{sign}(x)|\cos\frac{\pi}x|$. Show $f(x)$ has points of non-differentiability in any neighbourhood of $x=0$ and general help.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, limits, derivatives

> Let $f(x)=x^2\operatorname{sign}(x)|\cos\frac{\pi}x|$.
>
> Show that $f(x)$ has points of non-differentiability in any
>   neighbourhood of $x=0$.

We have already shown differentiability at $x=0$.

My original post was to verify a step in my work but I've realised whilst typing up here that it is not valid for another reason, so I have reformed the question so that I would still like an answer to the question above but also to the question asked below as it addresses roughly the step I was unsure of in my approach.

> In general to show whether or not $f(x)=g(x)+h(x)$ is differentiable
>   can we do the following?:
>
> Say $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{g(x+h)+h(x+h)-g(x)-h(x)}h$$ exists or
>   we're done. Then to show $$\lim_{h\rightarrow
>  0}\frac{g(x+h)+h(x+h)-g(x)-h(x)}h=\lim_{h\rightarrow
>  0}\frac{g(x-h)+h(x-h)-g(x)-h(x)}{-h}$$ can I now say this it true if
>   and only if $$\lim_{h\rightarrow
>  0}\frac{g(x+h)+h(x-h)-g(x)-h(x)}h=\lim_{h\rightarrow
>  0}\frac{g(x-h)+h(x+h)-g(x)-h(x)}{-h}?$$ i.e. I've moved the
>   $h(\delta\pm h)$s. I'm sure we can do this if $\lim_{h\rightarrow
>  0}h(\delta\pm h)$ exists but $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}f(\delta\pm h)$ can
>   exist without $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}h(\delta\pm h)$ existing, and in
>   the case $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}h(\delta\pm h)$ does not exist I'm not
>   sure if this step would be valid.

Thanks and sorry if this post was all over the place.

Answer (score 2):

If $f(a) = 0$ and $f'(a)\ne 0,$ then $|f(x)|$ is not differentiable at $a.$ Proof: Suppose WLOG $f'(a)>0.$ 
In the following we assume $x$ is close to, but not equal to, $a.$ The first thing to notice is that $f(x) > 0$ for $x>a$ and $f(x) < 0$ for $x<a.$ Thus if $x>a,$

$$\frac{|f(x)|-|f(a)|}{x-a}=\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \to f'(a)$$

as $x\to a^+.$ Similary,

$$\frac{|f(x)|-|f(a)|}{x-a}=\frac{-f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} = -\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\to -f'(a)$$

as $x\to a^-.$ Thus the limit fails to exist.

To finish the problem you just need to find lots of points where you can apply the above. (It may be helpful to notice that $|f(x)| = |x^2\cos\frac{\pi}x|.$)

Comment: This is actually very easy, thanks

Answer (score 1):

In general, $|f(x)|$ has a point of non-differentiability  <strike>every time $f$ changes from positive to negative (or vice versa)</strike> when $f(x) =
 0$ and $f'(x) \neq 0$. Does this help?

Comment: I'm sure it will, thanks- is this easy to show, it looks like it should be?

Comment: Use the chain rule: $\frac{d}{dx} |f(x)| = f'(x) \frac{d}{du} |u|_{u=f(x)}$, and $\frac{d|u|}{du}$ is infinite wherever $u = 0$. You can do it more formally with epsilons and deltas if you need.

Comment: That's actually not true. For example $|x^3|$ is differentiable at $0.$ Also your comment is incorrect. You can't use the chain rule because the hypotheses of the chain rule theorem are not satisfied. (And you don't want to say "infinite", because there is nothing infinite happening there.)

Comment: @zhw. You're right. I don't know what I was thinking; I must have gotten the first and second derivatives confused (if you think like a physicist, the second derivative of $|x|$ is just $2 \delta(x)$, so it is infinite at $x = 0$).